# Simple upper bound on the probability that the sum of $n$ dices rolls is equal to the most likely total

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, cryptography

Suppose $n$ $s$-sided (and fair) dice and are rolled, and consider the most likely value their total will take. Is there a simple / easy to state upper-bound on the probability that this total is rolled?

I know you can bound this accurately using generating functions, but to use in the proof I'm working on requires summing over this probability for a range of (large) $n$ values,  which gets too complicated. I imagine it can also be approximated it using some distribution, but it's for a crypto proof so I really need an upper bound. I'm crudely upper bounding this with $1/s$ at the moment for all $n$. This follows by induction on n. Letting $X_i$ denote the distribution of the $i$th dice roll

For $n = 1, Prob[X_1 = z] = 1/s$ for all $z \in [1, s]$, so the base case holds.

Assume true for $n=k$, so $max_{z \in [k, ks]} Prob[\sum_{i = 1}^k {X_i} = z] \leq  1/s$.

Then for $n = k+1$, and each $z \in [k+1, (k+1)s]$:

$Prob[\sum_{i = 1}^{k+1} {X_i}=z$]
                     $ = \sum_{h \in [k, ks]} Prob[X_{k+1} = z - \sum_{i = 1}^k X_i | \sum_{i = 1}^k X_i = h]Prob[\sum_{i = 1}^k X_i = h]$
$\leq \sum_{h \in [z - s, z-1]}1/s^2 = 1/s$,
where the final inequality follows since by the induction hypothesis $Prob[\sum_{i = 1}^k X_i = h]\leq 1/s$ and $Prob[X_{k+1} = z - h] = 1/s$ if $h \in[z - s, z-1]$ and $0$ otherwise.

I was wondering if there is any tighter (for large $n$) but still simple upper bound?

Comment: how do you know you can bound by 1/s?

Comment: What about Chebyshev's inequality? You have the expectation and variance of your random variable, and the most likely value is going to be (very near) the expectation.

Comment: The standard deviation of your sum is on the order of $\sqrt{ns}$, so I’d expect a bound of $C/\sqrt{ns}$ should do it, for some unspecified constant C.

Comment: I think Chebyshevs inequality is for lower bounds

Comment: @JorgeFernández Err, no. It upper bounds the probability of deviating from the expectation.

Comment: ooh, I read the question wrong, I thought OP wanted the probability the same sum comes out twice.

Comment: Interesting, thank you very much for the suggestions. Is there a way to use Chebyshev's inequality / the standard deviation to get an absolute upper bound (e.g., the probability will always less than or equal to some value), as opposed to just being unlikely to be exceed a given probability?

Comment: In order to understand your question, do you know the answer for some non-trivial $n$ and $s$, for example $n=2$ and $s=5$, and can you tell us what it is?

Comment: @HelenW I don't understand your last comment. Chebyshev's (or Markov, 's or any concentration inequality -- you could also consider Hoeffding here, for instance) gives you an "absolute" upper bound on the probability of some event.

Comment: For $n = 2$ and $s = 6$, the most likely total is $7$, with probability $1/6$. For $n = 3$ and $s = 6$, the equally most likely totals are 10 and 11, hit with probability $27/216$.

Comment: so how exactly do we use chebyshev?

Comment: @ClementC. sorry I'll have to take another look at the inequalities. I thought though that these bound deviation from the mean, rather than giving a definitive upper bound? By absolute /definitive upper bound I meant some term x such that $max_{z\in [n, ns]}Prob[\sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \leq z] \leq x$ where $n$ is the number of dice rolled, and $s$ is the number of sides, and $X_i$ is the distribution of the $i$th dice.

Comment: You're tight, in that Chebyshev is to argue aboit deviations from the mean. But at first glance, your probability distribution (convolution of n discrete uniform distributions) is log-concave, hence unimodal; and the most likely value (the mode) is the mean (or very close to it). Isn't it?

Comment: I said that the bound should be on the order of $1/\sqrt{ns}$, but it's actually $1/(s \sqrt{n})$ - the variance of a single die is on the order of $s^2$ and so the variance of the sum of $n$ such dice is on the order of $s^2 n$; the standard deviation is then on the order of $s \sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @MichaelLugo - Indeed and, as my answer shows, a constant of $1.6$ is enough.  Meanwhile $1.59$ is too small when $s=2$ and $n$ is large

Answer (score 2):

A good approximation for large $n$ is to note (rescaled) convergence in distribution to a normal distribution where the variance of the sum is $n\frac{s^2-1}{12}$ and so the probability of a value near the expectation of $n\frac{s+1}{2}$ will be about $\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}=\sqrt{\frac{6}{\pi n(s^2-1)}}$.

If you want to simplify this and remove the $-1$, then the worst case will be when $s=2$ in which case $s^2-1 = \frac34 s^2$ making the approximation  $\sqrt{\frac{8}{\pi}}\frac1{s\sqrt n}$.  Since $\sqrt{\frac{8}{\pi}} \approx 1.596$, a further simplification on the conservative side is $\dfrac{1.6}{s \sqrt n}$

For $s=2$ this is an very good upper bound as $n$ increases for the true value of $\frac{n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}{2^n}$: for example with $s=2$ and $n=100$ it gives $0.08$ when the true probability of the mode is about $0.079589$.  For larger $s$ it is only a small multiplicative amount too high: for example with $s=6$ and $n=36$ it gives about $0.044444$ for the probability of the mode when the true value is about $0.038761$.